# How to backup a remote SVN repo while you have not had admin rights?

Tags: svn, backup, codeplex

I mean you have not access to svnadmin, neither you have access to its files system. I'm going to backup source of my project in codeplex.com.

Many Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I used:

```
svnsync initialize file:///d:/fardis_repo https://fardis.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

but got error:

```
svnsync: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

Comment: duplicate of [Can you backup/create a dump of a subversion repository without direct access to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984237/can-you-backup-create-a-dump-of-a-subversion-repository-without-direct-access-to)

Answer (score 3):

To use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html), you first must create a pre-revprop-change hook script in your local repository.

If you've created your local repository on d:\fardis_repo, then go to
d:\fardis_repo\hooks, and create a file named "pre-revprop-change.bat" in that folder.
The "pre-revprop-change.bat" should contain one single line:

```
exit 0
```

That's all. After that, your command

```
svnsync initialize file:///d:/fardis_repo https://fardis.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

will work just fine.

Comment: may tnks to your solution. But by following your instruction I got error: svnsync: Storage of non-regular property 'svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url' is disallow
ed through the repository interface, and could indicate a bug in your client

Comment: Make sure you use svnsync with the same version as you used to create the repository. Or use the latest version. the error indicates a bug in svnsync.

Comment: My source repository is codeplex.com, that is originally a TFS source control management it just have a SVN bridge, may it be the root cause of problem?

Comment: That might be it. You could search whether this issue has been reported already or if not, file a new issue about this: http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: on linux, the file is `hooks/pre-revprop-change` (no extension) and it must be executable

Answer (score 0):

Use svnsync: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html

Comment: I used svnsync bu I got error. Please see my update at question.